# JSON Result for Flot Chart Data Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, flot

I try generates bar chart using flot chart, I got a problem.

I have Json response like this below :

```
[{"label":"Total Sales",
  "color":"#4345D1",
  "data":"[['09-21-2016',3],['09-19-2016',1],['09-13-2016',2],
           ['10-21-2016',2]]"
}]
```

but chart never shown, I guess "data" value may contains double quotes ("),
how to convert them, that can be used in correct format, like this :

```
[{"label":"Total Sales",
  "color":"#4345D1",
  "data": [['09-21-2016',3],['09-19-2016',1],['09-13-2016',2],
           ['10-21-2016',2]]
}]
```

Additional Coding :

Here are mysql query data source

```
select 'Total Sales' as label, 
concat('[',group_concat("[",concat('\"',trxdate,'\"',",",qty),"]"),']')
as data 
from(
  select 
    DATE_FORMAT(trxdate,'%m-%d-%Y') as trxdate,
    sum(quantity) as qty from Journals
    group by 
        DATE_FORMAT(trxdate,'%m-%d-%Y') 
 ) as A;
```

So I put them into nodejs as REST API,

and then here are service adapter :

```
$http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: vm.barsrc
    }).then(
      function successCallback(response) {
        var datArr = response.data[0];
        var datachart = ( datArr.data ).replace('"','').replace('"','');
        var result = [
          {
            label: datArr.label,
            color: datArr.color,
            data: datachart
          }
        ];
        vm.StackedBarDataset = result;

      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        ...
      }
    );
```

Thank you in advanced.

@derek :

[image: still same result]

[image: and chart not shown]

Comment: Show code that is generating the JSON

Comment: hi @derek, additional coding's added. thanks

Comment: try switching concat('[',group_concat("[",concat('\"',trxdate,'\"',",",qty),"]"),']') with
CAST(CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_ARRAY(trxdate, qty)),']') AS JSON)

Comment: i got errors :
{ [Error: UNKNOWN_CODE_PLEASE_REPORT: Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function cast_as_json: "Invalid value." at position 2.]
  code: 'UNKNOWN_CODE_PLEASE_REPORT',
  errno: 3141,
  sqlState: '22032',
  index: 0 }

Comment: try just CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_ARRAY(trxdate, qty)),']')

Comment: still same... image attached...

Comment: Dont pass data as  string, it should be an array, remove the quotes from the dataChart @FirmanHidayat

Comment: @parthmahida yes I think that's a suspect, but how come to convert them, as I told in the above question.

Comment: Call both value, in separate column and in while loop the returned data, set them as an array(trxdate,qty). Prepare data format for chart outside by php not in sql.@FirmanHidayat

Comment: @parthmahida we did not use php, but nodejs as a back-end service, but I will try break apart using while loop into array object(), anyway... thanks.

Comment: This is a good question but the answer is not clear enough. Did the problem already been solved?.